Extension of Dirichlet Divisors in Gauss Circle Integral Point Problem
Dirichlet Divisors
A well-known problem in number theory is to study the sum of divisor functions $d(n)$:
$D_2(x)=\sum_{n\leq x} d(n)$,
so $D_2(x)$ can be expressed as the number of the integer points in  $uv \leq x,u\geq 1,v\geq 1$.
Dirichlet has proved:
$D_2(x)=x(\log x+2\gamma -1)+\triangle_2(x)$,
$\triangle_2(x)=\sqrt{x}-2\sum_{u=1}^{u=\sqrt{x}}\{x/u\} +\omicron{(1)}$
and $\triangle_2(x)<<x^{1/2}$.
Extension of Dirichlet Divisors in Gauss Circle Integral Point Problem
For $x>2$, $A_2(x)$ is the lattice count of the circle $u^2+v^2\leq x$.
Please prove if $A_2(x)$ can be represented by $A_2(x)=\pi x+R_2(x)$, where
$R_2(x)=2\sqrt{2x}-8 \sum_{u=1}^{u=\sqrt{x/2}}\{\sqrt{x-u^2}\} du+\omicron{(1)}$.
Then from this, derive that $R_2(x)<<x^{1/2}$.
I am stuck,please help. Thanks.


Show you have a little worked at least by a small Web "enquiry". Besides, your title mentions "Dirichlet divisors" : where do we find them in your question ?


Thank you.I'm going to look at the book, and I'm going to write this question more clearly.
